# Conditional statement inside JSX in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement

I want to set my state inside JSX expression and show my component if the condition is true. How can i achieve that? i tried this this first :

```
{(currenMonth !== item.orderDate)
                && (setCurrentMonth(item.orderDate) && <Item name={getMonthFromString(item.orderDate)} active />)
              }
```

In a second solution i've created this function :

```
const ProductsList = () => {
  const [currenMonth, setCurrenMonth] = useState('');
  const renderItem = (month) => {
        if (currenMonth !== month) {
          setCurrenMonth(month);
          return <Item name={getMonthFromString(month)} active />;
        }
        return null;
      };
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
            data={products}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  { renderItem(item.orderDate) }
                </View>
              );
            }}
     />
   </View>
  );
}
```

But i'm getting an Error `[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]`

Comment: You shouldn’t set state and check it inside a conditional. Create a separate function that gets called outside, and then in the conditional check if the state is true.

Comment: I've edited my code can you please check what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways: practically the way you're doing it inside JSX and then a separate rendering function. I'll recommend the latter. But mentioned, `render` is not part of setting state. So you actually have two separate problems.

```
...
const renderMonthItem = () => (
  (<yourConditionals> ? <Item ... /> : null;
)

...

return (
  <View> ...
    { renderMonthItem() }
  ... </View>
);
```

Comment: I've edited my code can you please check what i'm doing wrong ?